# Swift2 - Using Alamofire 3 in nested JSON

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

I have the following JSON:

```
{
  "_embedded": {
    "modifier_groups": [
      {
        "_embedded": {
          "options": [
            {
              "id": "8kT9KTX7",
              "name": "Perfect",
              "open": false,
              "pos_id": "8kT9KTX7",
              "price_per_unit": 0
            },
            {
              "id": "zRcEkcj8",
              "name": "Overcooked",
              "open": false,
              "pos_id": "zRcEkcj8",
              "price_per_unit": 0
            }
          ]
        },
        "id": "eMiy4iR4",
        "maximum": 1,
        "minimum": 1,
        "name": "Temperature",
        "required": false
      },
      {
        "_embedded": {
          "options": [
            {
              "id": "E5cpac84",
              "name": "Tomato",
              "open": false,
              "pos_id": "E5cpac84",
              "price_per_unit": 0
            },
            {
              "id": "GkiREiyL",
              "name": "Cheese",
              "open": false,
              "pos_id": "GkiREiyL",
              "price_per_unit": 100
            }
          ]
        },
        "id": "kMT85Tay",
        "maximum": null,
        "minimum": 1,
        "name": "Toppings",
        "required": false
      }
    ]
  },
  "count": 2,
  "limit": 20
}
```

So there are modifier group names (e.g. "Temperature" and "Toppings"), and group options (e.g. "Perfect" and "Overcooked" for "Temperature" group).

What I am trying to do is build a `[String]` such as:

```
["Temperature - Perfect", "Temperature - Overcooked", "Toppings - Tomato", "Toppings - Cheese"]
```

What would be the quickest way to go about that?

Currently, I first extract the groups into a `[String]` using `valueForKeyPath`:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, url, headers: headers, encoding: .JSON)
        .responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
                case .Success(let JSON):                        
                    let jsonData = JSON as? NSDictionary
                    let groupNames = jsonData?.valueForKeyPath("_embedded.modifier_groups.name")
```

But how would I get from there to drilling deeper into the group options so that I append them into the `[String]`?

**UPDATE**

I tried this but it's not returning anything:

```
var mods = [String]()

let modGroups = jsonData?.valueForKeyPath("_embedded.modifier_groups")

if let modGroups = modGroups {
    for modGroup in modGroups as! [AnyObject] {
        let groupOptions = modGroups.valueForKeyPath("_embedded.options")
        if let groupOptions = groupOptions {
            for groupOption in groupOptions as! [AnyObject] {
                mods.append("\(modGroup) - \(groupOption)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it:

```
var mods = [String]()

let modGroups = jsonData?.valueForKeyPath("_embedded.modifier_groups") as? [NSDictionary]

if let modGroups = modGroups {
    for modGroup in modGroups {
        let groupOptions = modGroup.valueForKeyPath("_embedded.options") as? [NSDictionary]
        if let groupOptions = groupOptions {
            for groupOption in groupOptions {
                mods.append("\(modGroup.valueForKey("name")!) - \(groupOption.valueForKey("name")!)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```